# Unset Values from an Array that Match another Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

What would be the quickest and most efficient way of ensuring that the values that match $config['a'] are not set in $config['b']?

In this case Sunday 14 should be unset from $config['b']['Hours']['Sunday']

```
$duplicates = array_intersect($config['a']['Hours'], $config['b']['Hours']);
```

Gives me an error, *"Notice: Array to string conversion"*, and incorrect results, so either my array has been constructed incorrectly or my approach is incorrect.

**Here is the array;**

```
    $config  =  array(
                "a" => array(
                    "Hours" => array(
                        "Sunday" => array(12,13,14,15,16),
                    ),
                ),
                "b" => array(
                    "Hours" => array(
                        "Sunday" => array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14,17,18,19,20,21,22,23),
                        "Monday" => array(0,1,2,3,4,5,19,18,19,20,21,22,23),
                        "Tuesday" => array(0,1,2,3,4,5,19,18,19,20,21,22,23),
                        "Wednesday" => array(0,1,2,3,4,5,19,18,19,20,21,22,23),
                        "Thursday" => array(0,1,2,3,4,5,19,18,19,20,21,22,23),
                        "Friday" => array(0,1,2,3,4,5,19,18,19,20,21,22,23),
                        "Saturday" => array(0,1,2,3,4,5,8,19,20,21,22,23,24),
                    ),
                ),
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_intersect` does not work recursively, as specified in the documentation: https://secure.php.net/array_intersect.

It iterates and compares values as strings, thus the error, because it tries to use value `array(12,13,14,15,16)` as string and fails.

The correct way in your case would be to compare keys first using `array_keys()`, then for the keys that exist use `array_intersect()` or `array_diff()`.

**Edit:**

This example should work in the desired way:

```
$duplicateKeys = array_intersect(array_keys($config['a']['Hours']), array_keys($config['b']['Hours']));
$duplicates = [];

if(!empty($duplicateKeys) && is_array($duplicateKeys)) {
    foreach($duplicateKeys as $key) {
        $duplicates[$key] = array_intersect($config['a']['Hours'][$key], $config['b']['Hours'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever Sod!  Works great, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To remove from array `b` values, presented in corresponding 'a', use array_diff function

```
foreach($config['a']["Hours"] as $k => $v) { 
      $config['b']["Hours"][$k] = array_diff( $config['b']["Hours"][$k], $v);
    }
```

Comment: Might be problematic if `$config['b']["Hours"][$k]` doesn't exist. Although, if the `b` array always contains all keys, it is not a problem.

Comment: I guess that contains. I hope OP add a check if it'not so